Winding Number, Argument Principle, and Essential Singularities
I have some questions about the winding number.
Let $f \in H(\Omega \backslash \{z_0\})$ where $\Omega$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{C}$. Furthermore, let $\gamma \subset \Omega \backslash \{z_0\}$ be a closed curve lying in $\Omega$ and containing in its interior $z_0$. I know from my textbooks and class that, provided $f$ is meromorphic in $\Omega$, we have
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{f(\gamma)}\frac{1}{z}dz
= \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma} \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}dz = \# \text{zeros lying in } \gamma - \# \text{poles lying in } \gamma  = \# \text{zeros lying in } \gamma - \text{pole order of }z_0$$
where we count with multiplicity. So in our particular case we should find the integral gives $  \# \text{zeros lying in } \gamma - \text{ the pole order of }z_0.$
I wanted to investigate the behavior of the winding number when there are essential singularities. I broke up the analysis into two cases since Picard's Theorem gives us either $f$ hits $0$ infinitely often in neighborhoods of $z_0$ or $f$ never hits $0$.
Former Case:
If a zero belongs to $\gamma$ then the integral diverges.
If $\gamma$ does not contain any zeros of $f$, then it seems to me that we get the winding number of the curve $f(\gamma)$; however, it gives us no information on the number of zeros inside $\gamma$. My question here would be that of whether or not the winding number of $f(\gamma)$ is constant (across choices of $\gamma$) provided $\gamma$ is sufficiently small and does not contain a zero.
Latter Case:
Here it seems again to me that we just get the winding number of the curve $f( \gamma)$, but I don't know if the winding number has any significance or constancy. I do know, as well, that in this case $f'(z)/f(z)$ cannot have a simple pole.
To be more general, is there any significance to closed loop integrals containing points of essential singularity when the integrals can be computed? Or is it the case that essential singularities are too ill behaved and therefore the such integrals bear no relation to more general properties about $f$?

You can answer at least some of your questions by using a better form of the Argument Principle, i.e. the one that uses cycles not curves and is based off the homologous form of Cauchy-Goursat.
